# Apple Watch: Input number by Digital Crown like Alarm app

Tags: watchkit

How to increase/decrease number by Digital Crown like Alarm app?

https://www.apple.com/watch/timekeeping/

Answer (score 2):

As of WatchOS 2, it is now possible to access the Digital Crown for certain kinds of input.

To do so, create a `WKInterfacePicker`. The items presented for the user to select between can be text, images, or a combination of both.

To use the WKInteracePicker, add it your interface in your WatchKit App and add an outlet to your interface controller in your WatchKit Extension. Then, for the interface controller call `myPicker.focus()`.

See the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfacePicker_class/index.html) for fuller information.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, third-party developers have no access to the digital crown.

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI, you could use a`Picker` or `Slider` to input numbers. If you want to do something custom with the crown, look at the `digitalCrownRotation` modifier which you can hook up to a `@State` or `@Binding` and use in other parts of your UI or send to your model.